# Can a person be subjected to long term physical pain as a result of psychological abuse

Tags: pain

Can psychological abuse in the past lead to [long term physical pain in the present](https://www.healthline.com/health/chronic-pain)?

Pain will usually become less severe as the injury heals, but what about pain not resulting from physical injury?  How does that happen and how can it be sorted out?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Questions which are seeking advice for personal medical reasons are off topic on here. The problem is that what you are describing **could** be a psychological problem, but it could also be a physical problem. You need to see a doctor about the problem so that a proper diagnosis can be made which cannot be done here. I wish you luck

Comment: you need to change the title.

Comment: I have removed personal medical advice requested in the question reframed the question to fit the site's policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject area regarding this question is [psychosomatic disorders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychosomatic_medicine) and problems like what you describe can be difficult to deal with.

First of all it is imperative that **all physical and neurological causes of the pain are ruled out, including [neuropathic problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuropathic_pain), through medical examinations and tests**.

Psychosomatic medicine involves diverse specialties including psychiatry, psychology, neurology, internal medicine, surgery, allergy, dermatology and [psychoneuroimmunology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychoneuroimmunology).

Whenever any physical pain arises without physical injury, **it is important to see your doctor** to get the source of the pain checked out.  If you jump to the conclusion that it is all psychological without seeing your doctor first, you could cause serious problems now and further along in time.

It is possible that it could be psychological, but **only if medical examinations and tests have found no physical cause and the source is not anything but [psychological or psychiatrical](https://www.healthcareers.nhs.uk/explore-roles/psychological-therapies/differences-between-psychology-psychiatry-and-psychotherapy)**.

When a diagnosis is made that the pain is psychological, it doesn't mean that the pain is "all in your head".  The pain being felt is very real and in some cases can be debilitating.  You cannot just tell yourself it isn't real in order to stop the pain from being felt.

If the pain has a psychological cause, then therapy will be needed to deal with it.  The therapy will enable you to discuss the issues affecting you and enable you to live your life the best you can.

If the problem is not psychological, although psychological therapy will not deal with the pain, therapy can also help with [pain management](https://www.britishpainsociety.org/people-with-pain/) if the problem has been a long term problem and causing stress, depression, anxiety or other psychological problems.  There are also [complementary therapies](https://www.webmd.com/pain-management/guide/pain-management-alternative-therapy) which may help with both psychological and non-psychological problems.